# how to get log in ISA server 2006 C++ SDK without memory leak

Tags: c++

i wrote a method that get the all session log info with  isa server 2006   SDK

the main code is below and i have to use this code in do-while() to get all sessions information but this line make leak memory .

at the end i released the pointer of FPCLib::IFPCLogEntryptr but mem leak is still exist .
:( 
could you please help me this problem .

```
FPCLib::IFPCLogEntryptr =  FPCLib::IFPCLogContentPtr::Item(index)         
.
. // reading informationsuch as ip, url , byte send , ....
.
FPCLib::IFPCLogEntryptr.release();



hr = LOGFilter.CreateInstance("FPC.FPCFilterExpressions");                 
hr = LOGFilter->put_FilterType(FPCLib::FpcFilterType::fpcNoFilterType);                                            
FPClogviewer = FPCArray->LogViewer;                       
LOGContent   = FPClogviewer->GetLogContentOnline();                                                      
LOGContent->ExecuteQuery(LOGFilter,EXECUTEROWCOUNT);                                                  
FPCLib::IFPCLogEntryPtr FPCLogEntry;                                       
_bstr_t ClientIP;          
int  index= 0;                                             
do                                  
{                              
    index ++ ;              
    FPCLogEntry = LOGContent->Item(_variant_t(index));       
    ClientIP = FPCLogEntry->ClientIP;   
    FPCLogEntry.Release();  
}
while (1)
```

Comment: See my response to your earlier question about this

Answer (score 0):

the point is this line 
LOGContent->ExecuteQuery(LOGFilter,EXECUTEROWCOUNT);

the fist step change the do while to for

second- EXECUTEROWCOUN must be not larg number such as 1000000000

after 'for' you have to use LOGContent->EndQuery()

if you need still LOGGING  start function again